# Sort a String ArrayList based on order defined by another String Array

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've seen several other questions similar to this one but I haven't really been able to find anything that resolves my problem.

What would be the way to sort `numberWords` ArrayList based on `ORDER` array?

I'm not saying that `numberWords` must be `ArrayList`, it can be an `array` as well, but I thought it might fit better for `getStoredWords()` method as I should return `List<String>`.
Tried to compare `numberWords` to `ORDER` e.g. `numberWords.get(first).equals(ORDER[first])`, but it didn't work out the way it should.

```
public class WordStore {
    List<String> numberWords = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String[] ORDER = {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    };

    public void add(String numberAsWord) {
        numberWords.add(numberAsWord);
    }

    public List<String> getStoredWords() {
        
    }
}
```

Example tests:

```
public void insertedInArbitraryOrder() {
        WordStore wordStore = new WordStore();

        wordStore.add("three");
        wordStore.add("one");
        wordStore.add("two");
        wordStore.add("ten");
        wordStore.add("one");
        wordStore.add("five");
        wordStore.add("ten");
        wordStore.add("nine");
        wordStore.add("eight");

        assertThat(wordStore.getStoredWords(),
                contains("one", "one", "two", "three",
                        "five", "eight", "nine", "ten", "ten"));
    }
```

```
public void insertedInReverseOrder() {
        WordStore wordStore = new WordStore();

        wordStore.add("three");
        wordStore.add("two");
        wordStore.add("one");

        assertThat(wordStore.getStoredWords(),
                contains("one", "two", "three"));

    }
```

Comment: You need to map your words to their position in `ORDER` like Lino already suggested. For larger lists you might also consider using a `Map<String, Integer>` which maps the words (keys) to some order (in your case those could be the actual integer values).

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I think you're right, it wouldn't work with `binarySearch`

Answer (score 3):

It can be a one-liner, but **don't do it**, this approach is not good performance-wise.

```
numberWords.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ORDER::indexOf));               // DON'T use me
```

However, let's reuse the idea of the look-up based on the index of each word as the order definition.

You need two steps:

1. **Extraction**: Assign a numeric order to each word in `ORDERS`. The data structure `Map<String, Integer>` is suitable for it. The `HashMap` is useful for look-up based on the word.

   ```
   Map<String, Integer> orders = IntStream.range(0, ORDER.length)
           .boxed()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> ORDER[i], Function.identity()));
   ```

   The key is the word itself (for look-up) and value is its position or index.
2. **Sort**: Using the comparison based on the integers obtained through the map for each word.

   ```
   numberWords.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(orders::get));
   ```